# Where are the cube2 sauerbratren runtime binaries located?

Tags: filesystem, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have a raspberry pi 4.  It has cube2 sauerbraten intalled on it with `sudo apt install sauerbratren`.  I want to know where it's runtime binaries are located.  What directory would I find them in??  I looked in /bin and didn't find them there.  Where are they?  I am running raspbian bullseye.

Comment: Questions about basic use of the package manager `apt` belong on our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the package details it looks like they are likely to be found in a subdirectory of **/usr/share/games/sauerbraten**.

You can verify this using the which command:

which "*command name*"

so for example to find where the tar binary is located on the system you would do

`which tar`.

Note: this assumes you know the name of the command you are looking for.

You can read more from the man page:

`man which`

Alternatively, you could use the dpkg-query command:

dpkg-query -L "*package name*"

To see all the files installed by the sauerbraten package:

`dpkg-query -L sauerbraten`

Note: this will include images, help files, etc. installed by the package. As a result, it can include hundreds of files and make finding what you need difficult. You may want to pipe the results to grep to narrow the search (assuming you know the name or partial name of the file).

Other options include:

- Using the find command
- Using the locate command

More info on all of the above commands can be found in their respective man pages.

Comment: I tried `which sauerbraten` with no success.

Comment: To run sauerbraten, I run `sauerbraten` in the terminal.

Comment: that is the command I use.

Comment: try the dpkg-query or even better the find command

Comment: ahh, but that is the command.  It launches sauerbraten in normal mode.  The package is also called sauerbraten.

Comment: Just plain `dpkg -L sauerbraten` should work.  If it says **"package sauerbraten is not installed"**, then *you have the package name wrong* and we cannot help with that.  BTW *"I tried which sauerbraten with no success"* -> "No success" is an abstraction, you should say exactly what the result is that led to you to decide it was "no success".  **If `sauerbraten` alone runs the command, `which sauerbraten` says something about it.**

Comment: which sauerbraten said nothing at all.

Comment: Your system is busted/corrupted/defunct/fake, then.  Even if that is an alias, it will say `which: no sauerbraten in [directories from $PATH]`.   You may regard this as "nothing", but then, you are not the one seeking help...